# python sum values in df1 if loc in df2 is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still quite new to Python, and after looking intensively here on SO, I've decided to just ask.

I have a DataFrame, df

```
df
    NO2  NO2  NO3  DK1  DK2  
0   1.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
1   1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
2   2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
```

Now, what I want to do is sum up all values in row 0 that are equal to the value in column "DK1" (incl. itself) and return it in a new column.
Then after doing that for row 0, the same procedure for row 1, then row 2, etc.

Desired output:

```
df2
    NO2  NO2  NO3  DK1  DK2   Sum 
0   1.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0   3.0
1   1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  1.0   9.0
2   2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0   2.0
```

Comment: I apologize for the title, forgot to change it - also new on SO ;-)

Comment: I don`t understand. Why is the sum in the row 1 equal to 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare all values by `DF1` column, then multiple this column and last use `sum` per rows:

```
df['sum'] = df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0).mul(df['DK1'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   NO2  NO2.1  NO3  DK1  DK2  sum
0  1.0    3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
1  1.0    3.0  3.0  3.0  1.0  9.0
2  2.0    2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0))
     NO2  NO2.1    NO3   DK1    DK2
0   True  False  False  True   True
1  False   True   True  True  False
2  False  False  False  True   True

print (df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0).mul(df['DK1'], axis=0))
   NO2  NO2.1  NO3  DK1  DK2
0  1.0    0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0    3.0  3.0  3.0  0.0
2  0.0    0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: This might be a newbie-question, but my "Sum column" returns "1.01.01.0" (as in 1.0-1.0-1.0) instead of 3.0 in row 0 (same for the other rows as well)

Comment: @JeppeBay - Can you add `print (df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0).mul(df['DK1'], axis=0))` to question what return for you?

Comment: Never mind my question - that was a loading issue. You code worked perfectly. Thanks!
Does it work if the conditions are based on another df?

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael, I didn't know how to put this in a comment

```
  NO1    NO2   ...   DK1    DK2                     sum
0 28.4   28.4  ...   21.0   21.0                                  2121
1 28.2   28.2  ...   25.1   25.1    25,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,1
2 28.0   28.0  ...   25.1   25.1    25,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,1
3 28.0   28.0  ...   16.0   16.0                                  1616
4 28.0   28.0  ...   16.4   16.4                              16,416,4
```

Naturally, my actual dataset is not just ones the simple ones that I started out by - these are my actual values, and the result that I get. Does that help?

Comment: You could post the text to https://pastebin.com/ and paste the link.